# Retrieve initial value in mongodb with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

Inside a document I want to store unique phone numbers for each person in my collection like so:

```
phones: {
        "5551112222": {
            extension: "101",
            type: "Mobile"
        },
        "8005554444": {
            extension: "225",
            type: "Work"
        },
    },
name: {
  first: "john",
  last: "smith"
}
```

My PHP code to access this, which lets me access the extension and type, but how do I access the number part as $d obviously does not work as it just returns the whole array?

```
  foreach ($cursor['phones'] as $d) {
   echo 'number: ' . $d . '<br />ext. ' . $d['extension'] . '<br />type: ' . $d['type'];
```

Comment: It seems more like a JSON formatted string than an array... (Or am i mistaken?). BTW , what's the output of `var_dump($cursor['phones']);` ?

Comment: `array(1) { 5551112222=> array(2) { ["extension"]=> string(6) "101" ["type"]=> string(6) "Mobile" } }`

Comment: According to this output , there's only one "phone number" in the array , where the other one gone? (and the `name` element)

Comment: I was using that as an example. I have implemented the code with the above example, and this is the output of the `var_dump($cursor['phones']);` function. It does not include the `name` element as i'm only dumping `phones` as that's all I need access to, the `name` element is used on a different page but just stored in the same document on mongodb.

`array(2) { [5551112222]=> array(2) { ["extension"]=> string(3) "101" ["type"]=> string(6) "Mobile" } [8005554444]=> array(2) { ["extension"]=> string(3) "225" ["type"]=> string(4) "Work" } }`

Comment: Check if my answer helped you and update me if it works please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your `var_dump` output of the `$cursor['phones']` variable:

> array(2) { [5551112222]=> array(2) { ["extension"]=> string(3) "101"
>   ["type"]=> string(6) "Mobile" } [8005554444]=> array(2) {
>   ["extension"]=> string(3) "225" ["type"]=> string(4) "Work" } }

Change your code to:

```
  foreach ($cursor['phones'] as $number => $extra) {
      echo 'number: ' . $number . '<br />ext. ' . $extra['extension'] . '<br />type: ' . $extra['type'];
```

The reason is simple, when using the `foreach` loop in the following format:

```
foreach($arr as $d)
```

`$d` will contain the Value of the pair.

From the php manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

```
foreach (array_expression as $value)
    statement
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```

Answer (score 0):

`$d` will return the entire array, the foreach value of represents the array, `$d['extension']` should work though; does it? If you are trying to get the key then change your foreach to:

```
foreach($cursor['phones'] as $id => $d){
```

And use the `$id` var to output the number.